# Remove an item from IEnumerable

Tags: c#

I have IEnumerable of string type from checkbox list selected items as follows:

```
var list1 = chkboxlist.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(item => item.Selected == true).Select(item => item.Value);

if (list1.Contains("4"))
{
    //then remove that item from the list like

    for (int i = list1.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (list1.ElementAt(i) == "4") list1.ToList().RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

But item still exists in that list. It is not being removed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're calling `ToList()` which creates a *new* list which is a copy of the sequence, and then you're removing it from that list... but you're then basically throwing away the list.

You should convert the original sequence to a list and *then* remove the unwanted value... or you could just use `Except` to start with:

```
var list1 = chkboxlist.Items
                      .Cast<ListItem>()
                      .Where(item => item.Selected)
                      .Select(item => item.Value)
                      .Except(new[] { "4" });
```

Answer (score 3):

If you turn the enumeration into a list up front, you can remove the item:

```
var list1 = chkboxlist.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                      .Where(item => item.Selected == true)
                      .Select(item => item.Value)
                      .ToList();
```

That being said, you could just exclude the item first:

```
var list1 = chkboxlist.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                      .Where(item => item.Selected == true && item.Value != "4")
                      .Select(item => item.Value)
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: I don't want to remove item intially, Because I need to add some conditions if my list contains "4"

Comment: @user1882705 As I mentioned, you can convert it to a list first, then you can remove...